# Android paytm payment gateway response

Tags: java, android, payment, gateway, paytm

I have implemented Paytm payment system and everything is working fine with a web intent on top of my intent, money is deducted from customer's acc and its getting added on my account but after the transaction gets complete it gets stuck on a white page saying 'Redirect to app' which i believe i should write the code to redirect back to my app but i don't know how to do that because i couldn't find a onTransactionSucess() event or anything similar to that i also tried onTransactionResponse but still no response. I checked all the paytm documentation and tried contacting paytm support but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have added 'CALLBACK_URL' which is requied to verify the checksum.
As mentioned in paytm documentation

> CALLBACK_URL - Security parameter to avoid tampering. Generated using
>   server side checksum utility provided by Paytm. Merchant has to ensure
>   that this always gets generated on server. Utilities to generate
>   checksumhash is available [here](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/checksum/) .

Hope this should do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have added this variable to your code -

```
PaytmPGService service;
```

If you are using it than you can get all the payment related methods like this :

```
service.startPaymentTransaction(this, true,
            true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
                    System.out.println("===== onTransactionResponse " + inResponse.toString());
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        if (Objects.equals(inResponse.getString("STATUS"), "TXN_SUCCESS")) {
                            //    Payment Success
                        } else if (!inResponse.getBoolean("STATUS")) {
                            //    Payment Failed
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void networkNotAvailable() {
                    // network error
                }

                @Override
                public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // AuthenticationFailed
                }

                @Override
                public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // UI Error
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode, String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {
                    //  Web page loading error
                }

                @Override
                public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                    // on cancelling transaction
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionCancel(String inErrorMessage, Bundle inResponse) {
                    // maybe same as onBackPressedCancelTransaction()
                }
            });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That is all working but issue is my app gets stuck in verifyCheckSum.php page in backend. It does not get redirected automatically back to my app. Can i add something in my php page to close it or redirect back to my app?

Comment: If all things are working completely and you just want to redirect to back page you can use onTransactionResponse() method (see my code),if you can find any way to go back from that page than may be u can pass intent for back activity and i hope this helps

Comment: Transaction is working. Money is credited to my account but my app is stuck at backend php page verifychecksum.php.

Answer (score 0):

Change default callbackurl to suppose, 'http://yourdomain (ip address if checking on localhost)/pgResponse.php';.
Add following code to pgResponse.php

```
 <?php
        session_start(); 
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");



        // following files need to be included
        require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
        require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

        $paytmChecksum = "";
        $paramList = array();
        $isValidChecksum = "FALSE";

        $paramList = $_POST;
        $return_array= $_POST;
        $checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);//generate new checksum
        $paytmChecksum = isset($_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"]) ? $_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"] : ""; //Sent by Paytm pg


        //Verify all parameters received from Paytm pg to your application. Like MID received from paytm pg is same as your applicationís MID, TXN_AMOUNT and ORDER_ID are same as what was sent by you to Paytm PG for initiating transaction etc.
        $isValidChecksum = verifychecksum_e($paramList, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY, $paytmChecksum); //will return TRUE or FALSE string.
        $return_array["IS_CHECKSUM_VALID"] = $isValidChecksum ? "Y" : "N";
        unset($return_array["CHECKSUMHASH"]);
        $mid = $_POST['MID'];
      $orderid = $_POST['ORDERID']; 


        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/status?JsonData={"MID":"'.$mid.'","ORDERID":"'.$orderid.'","CHECKSUMHASH":"'.$checkSum.'"}',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Make Request'
        ));

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        $status= json_decode($resp)->STATUS;

//do something in your database


        $encoded_json = htmlentities(json_encode($return_array));



        ?>

        <html>
        <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-I">
             <title>Paytm</title>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                    function response(){
                            return document.getElementById('response').value;
                    }
             </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          Redirecting back to the app.....</br>
          <form name="frm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="response" name="responseField" value='<?php echo $encoded_json?>'>
          </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

In android studio:

```
public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
                            Log.d("Create Response", inResponse.toString());

                            String response = inResponse.getString("RESPMSG");
                            if (response.equals("Txn Successful.")) {
                                Toast.makeText(Bag.this,"Payment done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(Bag.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
```